# How to access property in "style" attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, background-image, css

Is there a possibility to access a i.e "`background-image:url()`" property inside an inline "`style`" attribute?
In other words going layers "deeper" than `attr('style')` does.

I want to manipulate the url inside `style="background-image:url(something);"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Setting CSS rules

The easiest way to modify a CSS property on elements in a jQuery object, is the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function:

```
$("selector").css("background-image", "url(something)");
```

If you want to set several CSS properties in one go, there is an "overload" of the function that takes an object and uses each member of this object to override the related CSS property:

```
$("selector").css({
    "background-image" : "url(something)",
    "color" : "red"
});
```

#### Getting CSS rules

If you need to read the current value of some CSS property, use another "overload" of `css`:

```
var backgroundImg = $("selector").css("background-image");
```

Comment: Using the `css()` function with two parameters instead of an object saves characters ;)

Comment: @DouweM: I was just editing that in as you posted your comment :)

Comment: How didn't I think of that! Maybe to tired.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to find the actual content of the `url()` 'function', but wouldn't it be easier just to use the following?

```
$('selector').css('background-image', 'url(something.png)');
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to manipulate the url inside
>   style="background-image:url(something);"

You would use that style for an element right?

```
$("selector").css('background-image', 'url(me.jpg)');
```

Comment: You still have to use `url()` around the path.